# How to use AWS SES inside lambda if a lot of emails should be sent in a short interval of time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I need to send email notifications. The process of determining whom and what emails to send is rather complex, so it's difficult to divide email sendings into small portions. Thus I plan to have a lambda that will run once a day, check data and send emails. The problem is that surprisingly despite SES daily sending limits are very high, its sending rate is very low. For example, I can send 50000 emails a day but only 10 emails per second. The question is what to do if I need to send only 100 emails a day but all of them the same moment (since AWS Lambda charges for running time and I can't just put "delays" during sending)? Does SES have some internal buffering?
The other related question: is SES send rate === sendEmail() calls (since one email can be sent to 50 recipients) or not?

Comment: did you check https://github.com/MoonMail/MoonMail ?

Comment: @alexandresaiz I'm not sure that's what I need. I need to solve the problem of buffering SES (if it really exists), that is, to create any number of emails and mark them for sending at one moment and don't care about their real sending time. Logic related to determining whom to send and how to handle bounces and complaintes is done and integrated into the existent app. So I'm not fond of using additional side services just for buffering SES.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a great use for a [SQS triggered Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html).  Throw all emails into an SQS queue and have Lambda pull them off and process them.  A big advantage of SQS is that you can use the default visibility timeout to determine how often you "see" a message again.  You don't specify your programming environment but in Java I could see something like:

```
public class ProcessSQSEvents implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void>{
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {

        AmazonSimpleEmailService simpleEmailService =
            AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().build();
        AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        for(SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords() {
            // presumably parse msg.getSQS.getBody() for the details

            String subject = // something gotten from the sqs body parsing
            String emailBody = // again, from the sqs body
            String from = // from the body
            String to = // you get the idea

            try {
                simpleEmailService.sendEmail( new SendEmailRequest()
                    .withSource(from )
                    .withDestination(new Destination().withToAddresses(to))
                    .withMessage(new Message()
                    .withBody(new Body(new Content(emailBody)))
                    .withSubject(new Content(subject))));
            }
            catch( MessageRejectedException mre ) {
                // the message was rejected - do not delete it from the queue
                continue;
            }

            String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl(msg.getEventSource() );

            sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl, msg.getReceiptHandle());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is a bit untested and there are likely optimizations (i.e. batch delete SQS messages) but the concept is that you read from the SQS queue and send as much as you can in a single Lambda invocation via SES.  If it fails, you do not delete it from the queue.  In this case you will get the message again in, by default, 30 seconds (the Default Visibility Timeout on your queue).  For greater robustness you could set up a redrive policy so that you don't try a message more than a set number of times.

The upside is that if SES can't send your message immediately you get to retry it later.  The possible downside is that an SQS triggered Lambda does cost a bit in that your SQS queue is being polled.

Comment: Looks like what I needed, thank you! I will check it tomorrow and if there are no any inevitable drawbacks for my case accept your answer. I use javascript, sorry, should have mentioned.

Comment: Do you know SES sendEmail() counts as one email for sending limits/rate or it depends on recipient count?

Comment: Well, according to the [SES FAQ - Limits and Restrictions](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#Limits_and_Restrictions), `Sending limits are based on recipients rather than on messages.`.  So that means to me that if you're sending a single email to 50 people then that counts as 50 even though `sendEmail` was called only once.

Comment: I've found that AWS Step Function suits my case better. It solves the problem SQS doesn't solve - scheduling email sender for running after a few seconds it finished previous run